# assigning Object references and performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

When I assign variable as such:

```
$app.prototype = {

   init: function() {

       self = this;
   }
}
```

is it actually creating a reference to "this" or copying the whole instance into the new variable?

just wondering for performance reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a re**f**erence, as long as `this` is an Object. In strict mode, `this` may also be a primitive (number, string, boolean), then it would create a copy.

A single assignment will never be a performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's not doing anything. The value of `this` is decided of how that function is invoked.

---

update:

Since `this` always references an context object, you don't need to mind assigning that reference into another variable. Anything in ECMAscript (except primitive values) is addressed with references.

Comment: this i'am aware of... no pun intended.

Comment: thanks for the update, you have actually cleared up another issue for me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a reference, *unless* strict mode is activated *and* `this` is a primitive value.

Also, it's not a local variable, because the variable is not prefixed with `var`.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan It does not affect performance. It's commonly used to get access to `this` inside another function within the block.

Comment: It does affect performance! Using this directly (where possible) would be faster - but not measurable :-)